# Can't install greenlet==dev even knowing greenlet greenlet (0.4.10) is installed

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install all the packages needed to use [Ajenti](http://support.ajenti.org/topics/1119-installing-on-raspbian/) on my raspberry pi 2. Originally I simply ran the wget command Ajenti has for automatic quick install. Everything went over smoothly until it needed to install greenlet==dev.

When it got to that point in the install it reports the following error back to the terminal:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   greenlet==dev (from versions: 0.4.2, 0.4.6, 0.3.2, 0.4.9, 0.4.10, 0.2,
>   0.4.7, 0.4.4, 0.3.3, 0.1, 0.3.4, 0.3, 0.4.0, 0.4.5, 0.4.9, 0.3.1, 0.4.1, 0.4.3, 0.4.10)
>
> Cleaning up...
>
> No distributions matching the version for greenlet==dev Storing debug
>   log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

If you investigate the log file it reads:

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/greenlet--dev/: 404
>   Client Error: Not Found    Will skip URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/greenlet--dev/ when looking for
>   download links for greenlet-dev
>
> Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
>
> URLs to search for versions for greenlet-dev:
>
> - https://pypi.python.org/simple/greenlet--dev/
>
>   Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/greenlet--dev/
>
>   Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/greenlet--dev/:
>     404 Client Error: Not Found
>
> Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/greenlet--dev/ when
>   looking for download links for greenlet-dev
>
> Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement
>   greenlet-dev
>
> No distributions at all found for greenlet-dev
>
> Cleaning up...
>
> Exception information: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122,
>   in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line
>   290, in run requirement_set.prepare_files(finder,
>   force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in
>   prepare_files
>       url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in
>   find_requirement
>       raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
>
> DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for greenlet-dev]

-[Pastebin of complete log file.](http://pastebin.com/qHPSL40C)

I've searched google for the error but haven't found anything concrete or relating to this specific issue. I made sure all the other packages were installed correctly. When I attempt to install or upgrade them on their own the report that they are all up to date with the latest version installed.

When you execute the command `pip list` it shows that everything is installed and list up to date versions as well. Including the base of greenlet version 0.4.10.

Ajenti allows me to log in, but once logged in it redirects to a completely blank page outside of the header/navigation bar. Some people report this issue with ajenti for other reasons which I can pin down later. I'd like to eliminate the possibility of it being related to greenlet-dev not being install or something it depends on not being properly installed.

Does anyone know what is/could be going wrong here and how to correct it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you run these commands for me please"pip install greenlet" then
"easy_install greenlet" then "/etc/init.d/ajenti restart" then "service agent restart" and tell me what the output is for every step?

Comment: For pip install greenlet:

`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): greenlet in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...`

For easy_install greenlet:

`error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-28952.write-test'`

Comment: Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: I amended my comment. It gives an error when you run easy_install greenlet. I've tried upgrading greenlet with the install with the --upgrade parameter and it says everything is up to date. Upgrading the entire OS has always been successful without error.

Comment: Can you please try `easy_install` but with `sudo` in front of it so it gets write permission

Comment: What about `apt-get install python-greenlet-dev`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following manual install method.

First run `wget http://repo.ajenti.org/debian/key -O- | apt-key add -` and add repository key

Next, add Add repository to /etc/apt/sources.list by running `echo "deb http://repo.ajenti.org/debian main main debian" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`

Then perform the install

`apt-get update
apt-get install -y ajenti 
apt-get install python-pip 
apt-get install python-dev 
apt-get install libevent-dev 
pip install -U gevent 
pip install greenlet==dev 
pip install -U psutil
/etc/init.d/ajenti restart`

`service ajenti restart`

That should complete the installation and start the panel on HTTPS port 8000. The default username and password are `root`, and `admin`, respectively.

[Source](http://support.ajenti.org/topics/1119-installing-on-raspbian/)

///Run all commands as sudo if you are having permission errors.